# Retry storing HTTP response into a variable until specific code

Tags: ruby, error-handling, http

I want to keep trying to get response until its code is 200 or unknown yet. In first case it should be stored in `response` variable. In another case I should raise any kind of exception.

```
  response = nil
  1.times do
    response = begin
      http.request request
    rescue Net::ReadTimeout
      puts "Net::ReadTimeout"
      retry
    end
    case response.code
    when "503"
      puts "servers are busy at #{Time.now}?"
      sleep 5
      redo
    when "200"
      "ok"
    else
      fail "#{response.code} at '#{request.path}'"
    end
  end
```

The `1.times` thing is taken from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696519/322020).

Answer (score 2):

The `1.times ... redo` thing is just awful. Replace that with an `until` loop, like this:

```
success = false
until success
  ...
  case response.code
  ...
  when "200"
    success = true
    "ok"
  else
    ...
  end 
end
```

Comment: Too imperative.

Comment: Ok, you didn't say anything about needing a functional pattern in your question. And besides, your original is already imperative. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, original is imperative -- this is why I posted it to ask how to make it more Rubyish.

Comment: There's nothing inherently 'un-Ruby' about imperative solutions.